# Amplify Federated Sign In not returning Email for Facebook

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm using AWS Amplify to add social signing. With google I'm getting the email of the user but it's missing in facebook.

This is my code:

```js
  federatedSignIn(provider: any): void {
    switch (provider) {
      case 'facebook':
          console.log("Authenticating using Facebook");
          Auth.federatedSignIn({ provider: CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider.Facebook });
          break;
      case 'google':
        console.log("Authenticating using Google");
        Auth.federatedSignIn({ provider: CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider.Google });
        break;
    }
     
  }
```

This is what the "Pre sign-up" Lambda sees as an event.

```js
{
    "version": "1",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "userPoolId": "us-east-xxxxxx",
    "userName": "Facebook_123456",
    "callerContext": {
        "awsSdkVersion": "aws-sdk-unknown-unknown",
        "clientId": "123456abcd"
    },
    "triggerSource": "PreSignUp_ExternalProvider",
    "request": {
        "userAttributes": {
            "email_verified": "false",
            "cognito:email_alias": "",
            "phone_number_verified": "false",
            "cognito:phone_number_alias": ""
        },
        "validationData": {}
    },
    "response": {
        "autoConfirmUser": false,
        "autoVerifyEmail": false,
        "autoVerifyPhone": false
    }
}
```

Userpool settings
[image]

[image]

Attribute mapping
[image]

Comment: Can you provide an actual example request and response (sanitized, of course) to demonstrate what it is currently returning?

Comment: Looks like this is covered in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48154575/how-can-users-sign-up-to-a-cognio-user-pool-through-facebook-when-email-attribut), which also has some useful comments on scenarios.

Comment: @George The event received by lambda is what it is currently returning.

Comment: @GaryArcher yes I think you are correct. But I'm unable to find any sample code on how to use the cognito event to call facebook api again. Do you know how to retrieve the access token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with `<amplify-facebook-button>` since it uses Identity Pool workflow instead of User Pool workflow. Creating a custom button with `federatedSignIn()`worked.

```html
  <button  slot="federated-buttons" (click)=customSignIn()>Facebook</button>
```

```js
  customSignIn(): void{
    Auth.federatedSignIn({provider: CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider.Facebook });
  }
```

More info: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/8823

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is following along with the [Amplify Dev Center guide for Social sign-in (OAuth)](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/social/q/platform/js/). The getUser() function is missing a return statement to return the currentUser variable.

```js
    function getUser() {
        return Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
          .then(currentUser => {
            setUser(currentUser);
            return currentUser;
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error in currentAuthenticatedUser:', error);
            logger.info('user Not signed in');
          });
      }
```

Once the return statement is added then you can access the email returned from the Facebook API by using: `user.attributes.email`